# Java; go back up a file tree until a specific folder

Tags: java

I want to recursively go backwards up a directory until I find a specific parent folder.

Basically what I'm after is

```
    while (!child.getParentFile().equals(greatGrandparent)) {
        // keep going backwards until it does
    }
```

Where `child` could be 10, 20, 50 levels underneath `greatGrandparent`

All I can find online is saying to start and grandparent and check each child until I find the child I'm looking for, but there could be a million children under the grandparent and I don't want to check them all when I know I just need to go back up the tree, if that makes sense.

Is there a standard pattern for this?

Comment: Are you saying continue until parent and the grandparent are the same? As thats what that code looks like..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with

```
while (!child.getParentFile().equals(greatGrandparent)) {
    child = child.getParentFile();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for simply this:

```
while (!child.getParentFile().equals(greatGrandparent)) {
    child = child.getParentFile();
}
```

If this is not what you are looking for, you'll need to explain your problem better.